# Unity- plataformas 2D, salto con OnCollisionEnter

Tags: unity2d

Intento hacer un juego básico en Unity por primera vez, un plataformas en 2D.
Al querer saltar no soy capaz de que solo salte cuando toca el suelo, salta siempre aunque no este en las plataformas, que tienen el Layer Ground.
Este es el script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
public class ControlPersonaje : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float velocidadMaxima = 1f;
    public float velocidad = 0.5f;
    private Rigidbody2D rigi;
    private Animator anim;
    private bool facingRight;
    private bool jump = false;
    public float jumpForce=9.9f;
    public bool grounded = false;
    public Transform pie;
    public LayerMask groundLayerMask;
    public enum GameState { Idle, Playing }; 
    public GameState gameState=GameState.Idle;
    public GameObject uiScore;
    private int puntos = 0;
    public Text puntosTexto;
    public float radio=0.1f;

    void Start()
    {
        uiScore.SetActive(false);
        rigi = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = this.GetComponent<Animator>();
        facingRight = false;
        Flip();
    }
    void Awake()
    {
    // Setting up references.
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col){
      if(col.gameObject.tag=="Ground"){
        grounded=true;
      }

    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(gameState==GameState.Idle &&(Input.GetKeyDown("up") ||   Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))){ 
            gameState=GameState.Playing;
            uiIdle.SetActive(false);
            uiScore.SetActive(true);

            if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && (grounded)){
              jump=true;
            }
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    { // mejor el fixed update para trabajar con fisicas

        if (gameState == GameState.Playing)
        { // si el juego se pone en marcha
            movimientoJugador(); 
        }
    }



    void Flip()
    {
        Vector3 v;

        if (facingRight)
            v = Vector3.Slerp(Vector3.right, Vector3.left, 1.0f);
       else
            v = Vector3.Slerp(Vector3.left, Vector3.right, 1.0f);

        facingRight = !facingRight;

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(v);
    }
    void movimientoJugador(){
        float mover = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        rigi.velocity = new Vector2(mover * velocidadMaxima, rigi.velocity.y);
        anim.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(mover));
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow)&& grounded) 
            jump = true;
        if (mover > 0 && !facingRight)

            Flip();

        if (mover < 0 && facingRight)

            Flip();

        if (jump) // esto es equivalente a if jump==true
        {
        // set el trigger del animator para saltar
        // añade una fuerza vertical al jugador para que salte
            rigi.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpForce));
            anim.SetBool("Jump",true);
        //anim.SetBool("Jump",false);
        // marca que no salte una vez que ya haya saltado
            jump = false;
        }
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) // cuando chocamos contra un enemigo
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Point")
        {
            IncrementarPuntos();
        }
    }

    public void IncrementarPuntos()
    {
        puntos++;
        puntosTexto.text = puntos.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Recuerdo haber tenido un problema similar, te recomiendo hacerle [Debug.log](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html)  de los valores en los momentos críticos (Función `Update()` y `movimientoJugador()`).  
por ejemplo un `Debug.Log("Jump ", jump);`

Answer (score 0):

Le he estado echando un vistazo a tu código y creo que el problema radica en que la variable *grounded* nunca vale false, por lo que cuando pulsas la tecla UpArrow, *grounded* siempre vale true y siempre se pone la variable de *jump* a true. Para solucionarlo bastaría con asignarle a la variable *grounded* el valor **false** cuando se vaya a saltar. Por ejemplo:

```
void Update()
{
    if(gameState==GameState.Idle &&(Input.GetKeyDown("up") ||   Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))){ 
        gameState=GameState.Playing;
        uiIdle.SetActive(false);
        uiScore.SetActive(true);

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && (grounded)){
          jump=true;
          //Aquí le decimos a grounded que no esta en el suelo
          grounded = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Espero que te haya servido de ayuda.
Un saludo.

Comment: Hola , muchas gracias por tu ayuda:  el problema en este caso es que , si dejo de saltar si pongo grounded a false donde tu marcas, pero el problema me viene cuando quiero que pueda saltar de nuevo, dado que para marcar que esta en el suelo, si uso OnTriggerEnter2D , marcando las plataformas como Trigger, el personaje se cae al vacio

Comment: en aclaración, el metodo OnCollisionEnter que tengo puesto para marcar cuando el personaje choca con la etiqueta Ground no me funciona tampoco

Comment: solucionado, al ser un juego en 2D el metodo OnCollisionEnter no funciona, tiene que denominarse OnCollisionEnter2D, gracias por la ayuda.